# pyOpenCL and 2D FFT

Tags: python, opencl, fft, pyopencl

I am using pyFFT to fourier-transform a 2D array using and then continue with another OpenCL program (here double it as an example):

```
gpu_data = cl_array.to_device(queue, tData2D)  
plan.execute(gpu_data.data)  
eData2D = gpu_data.get()  


ctx = cl.Context([cl.get_platforms()[0].get_devices()[0]])
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
mf = cl.mem_flags
eData2D_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=eData2D)
eData2D_dest_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, eData2D.nbytes)
prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
        //#define PYOPENCL_DEFINE_CDOUBLE     // uncomment for double support.
        #include "pyopencl-complex.h"    
        __kernel void sum(const unsigned int ySize,
                              __global cfloat_t *a,
                              __global cfloat_t *b)
        {
          int gid0 = get_global_id(0);
          int gid1 = get_global_id(1);

          b[gid1 + ySize*gid0] = a[gid1 + ySize*gid0]+a[gid1 + ySize*gid0];
        }
        """).build()

prg.sum(queue, eData2D.shape, None, np.int32(Ny), eData2D_buf, eData2D_dest_buf)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, eData2Dresult, eData2D_dest_buf)
```

This works perfectly fine. Now, instead of retrieving the data and recopy it in a buffer `eData2D = gpu_data.get()` and copy it right back to the GPU memory `eData2D_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=eData2D)`, I would like to keep using it.

I was expecting somethin like this:

```
gpu_data = cl_array.to_device(queue, tData2D)  
plan.execute(gpu_data.data)


ctx = cl.Context([cl.get_platforms()[0].get_devices()[0]])
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
mf = cl.mem_flags
eData2D_dest_buf = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, eData2D.nbytes)
prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
        //#define PYOPENCL_DEFINE_CDOUBLE     // uncomment for double support.
        #include "pyopencl-complex.h"    
        __kernel void sum(const unsigned int ySize,
                              __global cfloat_t *a,
                              __global cfloat_t *b)
        {
          int gid0 = get_global_id(0);
          int gid1 = get_global_id(1);

          b[gid1 + ySize*gid0] = a[gid1 + ySize*gid0]+a[gid1 + ySize*gid0];
        }
        """).build()

prg.sum(queue, eData2D.shape, None, np.int32(Ny), gpu_data.data, eData2D_dest_buf)
cl.enqueue_copy(queue, eData2Dresult, eData2D_dest_buf)
```

Which did not work. Is there a way to do that?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: It looks like you are creating a whole new context (`ctx = cl.Context(...)`) to run the second program. An OpenCL buffer is only valid for the context in which it was created, so you would need to make sure you use the same context for both OpenCL programs if you want to re-use the buffer like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a whole new context to run the second program:

`ctx = cl.Context(...)`

An OpenCL buffer is only valid for the context in which it was created, so you need to make sure you use the same context for both OpenCL programs/kernels if you want to re-use the buffer like this.

You could also re-use the command-queue, rather than creating a new one.